# How to detect OnResume and onPause on react native Es6

Tags: android, react-native, onresume, onpause

How can I detect any method from background to foreground es6?

Is this possible in React-native? and is there any class or tool that could help with this type of method?

Answer (score 7):

Try this, it working for me

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import {AppState, Text} from 'react-native'

class AppStateExample extends Component {

  state = {
    appState: AppState.currentState
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    AppState.addEventListener('change', this._handleAppStateChange);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    AppState.removeEventListener('change', this._handleAppStateChange);
  }

  _handleAppStateChange = (nextAppState) => {
    if (this.state.appState.match(/inactive|background/) && nextAppState === 'active') {
      console.log('App has come to the foreground!')
    }
    this.setState({appState: nextAppState});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Text>Current state is: {this.state.appState}</Text>
    );
  }

}
```

Comment: What about the component state? Like If we load one scene & loads another scene over it! Is there any method triggered like onPause OnResume specific to component not specific to App?

Answer (score 1):

As an update to the existing answer, `removeEventListener(type, handler)` has been [deprecated](https://reactnative.dev/docs/appstate#removeeventlistener) (since September 2021):

> Use the remove() method on the event subscription returned by
> addEventListener()

#### Using class component

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import {AppState, Text} from 'react-native'

class AppStateExample extends Component {

  state = {
    appState: AppState.currentState
  }

  eventListenerSubscription = null;

  componentDidMount() {
    this.eventListenerSubscription = AppState.addEventListener('change', this._handleAppStateChange);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.eventListenerSubscription.remove();
  }

  _handleAppStateChange = (nextAppState) => {
    if (this.state.appState.match(/inactive|background/) && nextAppState === 'active') {
      console.log('App has come to the foreground!')
    }
    this.setState({appState: nextAppState});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Text>Current state is: {this.state.appState}</Text>
    );
  }
}
```

#### Using hooks

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { AppState, Text } from 'react-native';

function AppStateExample() {
  const [appState, setAppState] = useState(AppState.currentState);
  var eventListenerSubscription;

  const _handleAppStateChange = nextAppState => {
    if (appState.match(/inactive|background/) && nextAppState === 'active') {
      console.log('App has come to the foreground!');
    }
    setAppState(nextAppState);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    //on mount
    eventListenerSubscription = AppState.addEventListener('change', _handleAppStateChange);
    return () => {
      // on unmount
      eventListenerSubscription.remove();
    };
  }, []);

  return <Text>Current state is: {appState}</Text>;
}
export default AppStateExample;
```