# React Native - How to detect home button is pressed or not?

Tags: react-native

I can know when the scene is on screen using following code:

```
this.subs = [
   this.props.navigation.addListener('didFocus', this.loadOfflineData)
];
```

But , if I want to detect when scene is out of focus. I 'm wondering what should I do .

Basically I want to detect if the user press home button and then I want to perform some action.

Any suggestions.

Comment: You can use [AppState](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/appstate) to determine whether the app is in the background.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [AppState](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/appstate) to know when an app is put into the background.

> `AppState` can tell you if the app is in the foreground or background, and notify you when the state changes.

Here is a simple example of using AppState:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {AppState, Text} from 'react-native';

class AppStateExample extends Component {
  state = {
    appState: AppState.currentState,
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    AppState.addEventListener('change', this._handleAppStateChange);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    AppState.removeEventListener('change', this._handleAppStateChange);
  }

  _handleAppStateChange = (nextAppState) => {
    if ( this.state.appState.match(/inactive|background/) && nextAppState === 'active' ) {
      console.log('App has come to the foreground!');
    } else {
      console.log('App has gone to the background!');
      // start your background task here
    }
    this.setState({appState: nextAppState});
  };

  render() {
    return <Text>Current state is: {this.state.appState}</Text>;
  }
}
```

Comment: The above solution is not working on Android when clicked on home button. According to documentation the inactive won't call for Android. Any ideas on how to achieve this on Android?

Comment: You are correct that cannot get `inactive` for Android, as `inactive` is an iOS state. You probably won't be able to replicate an iOS method in Android. You can see the java code used for AppState [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/c4806fada6532894e2242cf31f7145d2992e3a2b/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/modules/appstate/AppStateModule.java#L73), onPause causes the background notification to be sent. I don't see where the inactive would/could be sent.

Comment: on Android when I clicked on home button, it minimizes the app to background and home screen appears on the front, in this case the change event listener is not getting invoked. How to capture that event of home button click on android?

Answer (score 0):

I've done this with android and java using the android lifecycle. This should work in React Native (see EDIT down below). the developer.android.com forum: [this page](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#ActivityLifecycle)

In short:

- onCreate(): a user opens your app for the first time
- onStart(): app restarts
- onResume(): a user opens your app while it was active in the background
- onPause(): app goes out of focus
- onStop(): app is no longer visible
- onDestroy(): activity will be destroyed

[image]

In your case you should use onPause()

So a little code snippet for in java:

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

//do something

}
```

**EDIT:**

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50020342/how-to-detect-onresume-and-onpause-on-react-native-es6) tells you how to detect onPause and onResume in Reacte Native.

Code in that answer:

```
 import React, {Component} from 'react'
 import {AppState, Text} from 'react-native'

 class AppStateExample extends Component {

   state = {
     appState: AppState.currentState
   }

   componentDidMount() {
     AppState.addEventListener('change', this._handleAppStateChange);
   }

   componentWillUnmount() {
     AppState.removeEventListener('change', this._handleAppStateChange);
   }

   _handleAppStateChange = (nextAppState) => {
      if (this.state.appState.match(/inactive|background/) && nextAppState === 'active') {
       console.log('App has come to the foreground!')
     }
     this.setState({appState: nextAppState});
   }

   render() {
     return (
       <Text>Current state is: {this.state.appState}</Text>
     );
   }

 }
```